# XHR failed loading GET in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

This is strange because I am trying to get a servlet response from my ajax and the first time I load the page and trigger the request, I get the right response in the console log but the next time, I try clicking on the button to get the response it keeps giving me the error.

```
XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/TestApplication/HomeServlet?format=json".
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ Home.jsp?apiname=&apiendpoint=&apiversion=&check=Check:33
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

This is baffling me and I would like to know why am i getting such a bizarre response.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajaxresponse">

</div>
<form>
 API Name:<br>
  <input type="text" id = "apiname" name="apiname">
   API ENDPOINT:<br>
  <input type="text" id ="apiendpoint" name="apiendpoint">
  <br>
  API VERSION:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiversion" name="apiversion">
   ACCESSIBLE:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="internet"> Internet<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="vpn"> VPN<br>
 <!-- 
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" formaction="Home" method="post" value="Submit"> -->
  <br>
    <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" value="Check">

</form> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
    $.ajax({
           url: 'HomeServlet',
           data: {
                  format: 'json'
               },
           error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
           success: function(data) {
               var $val1 = data.value1;
               var $val2 = data.value2;
              // $('#ajaxresponse').append('<p>'+$val1+'</p>');
            console.log(data.value1);
           },
            type: 'GET'
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to prevent the default behavior by passing the event to your anonymous function and calling `event.preventDefault()`. Submitting the form could have changed the url of the page which causes your ajax url to be different as well since you're referring to your servlet as a relative url. Can you see any differences between the successful and failed ajax calls?

Comment: @vi5ion:- Thanks a lot. It fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions can be possible:

1) Change input button type from **submit** to **button** and try again, as you are also submitting form by clicking on it as well which might be causing the issue.

2) Try event.preventDefault() on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to prevent the default behavior by passing the event to your anonymous function and calling `event.preventDefault()`. Submitting the form could have changed the url of the page which causes your ajax url to be different as well since you're referring to your servlet as a relative url.